# List file names from a directory and place output in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to find all text files in my directory and copy a list to text file. I am using a for loop to get the names. Then the output is being placed in the text file. However I am getting an indication of a `syntax error near unexpected token`$'do\r''`. What would be the best way to do this? Also for the text file name how could I save it with a date/timestamp name?

```
FILE_PATH="/my_folder/"
for f in $(find $FILE_PATH -type f -name '*.txt'); do
    echo "file '$f'" >> "$FILE_PATH"mylist.txt;
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `for` loop. In order for that `for` loop to execute, it first has to find all of the files that meet your criteria, then *substitutes* that list into your for loop. It means waiting for that ``find`to process before your`for` loop can even start to process the names. Plus, if there are lots of files, you can overload the command line and lose files you want to see.

Why not:

```
FILE_PATH="/my_folder"
find $FILE_PATH -type f -name '*.txt' > "$FILE_PATH/mylist.txt"
```

No need for a loop. No need to echo. Simple and clean.

Plus, you don't have issues with file names that may contain spaces.

Comment: Great! For some reason I keep getting this error `: Protocol errorass_concat.sh:`

Comment: What is that `errorass_concat.sh`? Are you sure the error is with this line? Add `set -xv` to the top of your shell script. This will print out each line as it executes, and will help show you where that _Protocol_ error is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `find` using pathname expansion:

```
FILE_PATH="/my_folder/"
for f in "$FILE_PATH"/* ; do
    test -f "$f" || continue       # not a regular file
    echo "$f"
done >| "$FILE_PATH/mylist.txt"    # >| force overwrite
```